# Hyperscan: undefined reference to `core2_memset

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

Hi I'm trying to build hyperscan 5.4.0 but, when building "unit-chimera" thhe terminal outputs this

> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_native.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_64.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_64.c.o):/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: more undefined references to` core2_memset' follow
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_native.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_64.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_64.c.o):/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: more undefined references to` corei7_memset' follow
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_native.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_64.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_64.c.o):/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: more undefined references to` avx2_memset' follow
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd128.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd256.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd384.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(limex_simd512.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function `memmove': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:36: undefined reference to` core2_memmove'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function `memmove': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:36: undefined reference to` core2_memmove'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(stream_compress.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` core2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(stream_compress.c.o):/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: more undefined references to `core2_memcpy' follow /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(hwlm.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `core2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function` memmove':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:36: undefined reference to `corei7_memmove' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function` memmove':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:36: undefined reference to `corei7_memmove' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(stream_compress.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `corei7_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(stream_compress.c.o):/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: more undefined references to` corei7_memcpy' follow
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(hwlm.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function `memset': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` corei7_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function `memmove': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:36: undefined reference to` avx2_memmove'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(runtime.c.o): in function `memmove': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:36: undefined reference to` avx2_memmove'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(stream_compress.c.o): in function `memcpy': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to` avx2_memcpy'
> /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(stream_compress.c.o):/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: more undefined references to `avx2_memcpy' follow /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(hwlm.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(database.c.o): in function` memcpy':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29: undefined reference to `avx2_memcpy' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(gough.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` core2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(gough.c.o): in function` core2_nfaExecGough16_queueInitState':
> /home/christian/Desktop/hyperscan/src/nfa/gough.c:1075: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(mpv.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `core2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(gough.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` corei7_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(gough.c.o): in function` corei7_nfaExecGough16_queueInitState':
> /home/christian/Desktop/hyperscan/src/nfa/gough.c:1075: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(mpv.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `corei7_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(gough.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to` avx2_memset'
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(gough.c.o): in function` avx2_nfaExecGough16_queueInitState':
> /home/christian/Desktop/hyperscan/src/nfa/gough.c:1075: undefined reference to `avx2_memset' /usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libhs.a(mpv.c.o): in function` memset':
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:59: undefined reference to `avx2_memset'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [unit/CMakeFiles/unit-chimera.dir/build.make:196: bin/unit-chimera] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:853: unit/CMakeFiles/unit-chimera.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2

I followed the official intel guide to get started (https://intel.github.io/hyperscan/dev-reference/getting_started.html#) and I tried to redo the process man times but without success.I have Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
user@host ~/src/hyperscan $ rm tools/hscollider/CMakeLists.txt
user@host ~/src/hyperscan $ cd build
user@host ~/src/hyperscan/build $ cmake .. -G Ninja -DFAT_RUNTIME=off
```

-DFAT_RUNTIME and rm of the CMakeList actually do the trick